# UIImageViews smaller than they should be

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I created a Twitter request which downloads user profile images and I populate them in a UICollectionView, but some of the pictures are smaller than others:

[image]

I want all pictures to be bigger, which is why I set the custom CollectionView cell to .scaleAspectFit:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    userImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    // Initialization code
}
```

I did the same in the storyboard setting for the UIImageView, but it doesn't work. What is the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.scaleAspectFill`. `AspectFit` only stretches the image as long as all the edges are still visible

Comment: Thank you, but it then sometimes just stretches the images in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

It works after having added the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

Comment: Oh sorry, still not so familiar with the rules.

Comment: @DrainOpener it is an answer. yoKurt, you didn't need to add your answer to the question. Answering yourself in the answer section is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Okay that was my first thought, too.